# How do מושב יקרו and שכינת עזו work in the Oleinu prayer?

Tags: tefilla, theology, aleinu-leshabeiach

I would like to understand in the Oleinu prayer 
what is meant by

(1) מושב יקרו Artscroll translates as “the seat of His homage” and

(2) שכינת עזו
Artscroll translates as “His powerful presence”

In the musaf kedusha it says 
כבודו מלא עולם
“His glory fills the world”

So why do “the seat of His homage” & “His powerful presence” have to be localised to “in the heavens above” and “in the loftiest heights” respectively while His glory fills the world.

Comment: Note many older works have Kisei Kevodo instead of Moshav Yekaro

Comment: @DoubleAA Both the _Mishneh Torah_'s [Seder ha-Tefilah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2700.htm#47) and [Siddur Rav Saadiah Gaon](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20685&pgnum=280) have "_Moshav Yekaro_". Also, the [Tur Orach Chayim 133](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x293) says that some say "_ve-Kise' Kevodo_", but it is incorrect, as "_u-Moshav Yekaro_" is the version in the _Sefer Heikhalot_.

Comment: Gentlemen, thank you for your interesting notes but the question is clear. The same question on localisation exists for Kisei Kevodo as for Moshav Yekaro.

Comment: Actually, an answer could make a distinction between _Yeqaro_ / _Uzo_ and _Kevodo_ to explain why the former is localized and the latter is not, but would have a problem if _Kevodo_ is both localized and fills the world.

Comment: Is your question on the text or on Artscroll? I.e. can a different translation be part of an answer?

Comment: @YEZ It depends on the translation - sorry that's all I can say.

Comment: I assume that means I am not bound to the Artscroll translation.

Comment: @YEZ That's right.

Comment: The author of the Aruch HaShulchan in his less commonly known sefer, Baruch She'amar writes that *Moshav Yekaro* was a change made by Christians because "yekaro" is the same gematria as yeshu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The יעב"ץ writes in his siddur (by aleinu) that מושב יקרו is a reference to the כסא הכבוד of [יחזקאל א' כ"ו](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%99%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%95).

Here is what the מלבי"ם says there:

> שראה דמות כסא המיוחד אל המלך לשבת עליו לשפוט מישרים ו**להנהיג הנהגת מלכותו**, כי משם תצא הנהגת מלכו של עולם ומשפטיו

And here is the מלבי"ם on [תהלים ס"ח ל"ה](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A1%D7%97_%D7%9C%D7%94) on the words ועזו בשחקים:

> ועזו בשחקים", הנהגת ה' ע"ש הפלא והנסים, נקרא בכתבי הקדש בשם גאות ה', שבו יתגאה על הטבע ויתנשא עליה, והנהגה זו קבועה בשחקים שהם למעלה מן השמים והמערכת, הנה "גאותו ועזו אשר בשחקים" **להנהיג הנהגה הנסיית** הוא "על ישראל" שזה ינהיג רק בעבורם וכפי מעשיהם אם יזכו לזה

And in ['תהלים ק"נ א](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A0_%D7%90):

> הללוהו ברקיע עוזו", שהיא **ההנהגה הסדורה על ידי הרקיע והגלגל** והמערכה עפ"י הטבע:

So rather than describing the locality of His presence, what aleinu seems to be describing is the two aspects of G-d running the world:

(1) His king-ship over the world in general and

(2) Either the miraculous way that He deals with Israel (if גבהי מרומים refers to שחקים), or how He runs the world through the stars (if גבהי מרומים refers to the רקיע).

I think the גבהי מרומים probably refers to שחקים since the context relates Him in reference to us (in the top of the heights, He is **our** G-d, there is no other) and also because מרומים is in plural like שחקים.