Source of the expression וכסא כבודו in עלינו
According to נוסח הגר״א the first paragraph of עלינו has "וכסא כבודו" rather than the standard "ומושב יקרו" (see מעשה רב 52). There is an interesting footnote in the סידור אשי ישראל which points out that the reason for avoiding "יקרו" is that its גימטריא is the same as "ישו"; however, it doesn't address why "וכסא" over "ומושב", and the fact that the expression "וכסא כבודו" occurs in full throughout היכלות רבתי (an older, perhaps original, source?) leads me to believe the numerical connection is but a mnemonic flight of fancy.
מנהג בני רומא, at least according to page 71 of this סידור, also uses the wording "וכסא כבודו".
What is the origin of this wording, and when was it first added into the prayer ritual?
​

What's the source for ומושב יקרו?

Heh... I don't know. But since סידור רב סעדיה גאון has מושב יקרו, I'm assuming that this is the original wording and curious when the synonymous כסא כבודו first came into play.

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43879

https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim,_Hekhalot,_Tractate_Hekhalot.5 Here both the terms מושב יקרו and כסא כבודו are used. I was unable to find any other early use of the term.

According to Wikipedia:

המשפט "שהם משתחווים להבל וריק ומתפללים אל אל לא יושיע" הושמט על ידי הצנזור – בעיקר בסידורי אשכנז – עקב טענה שהמילה "וריק" מכוונת לישו, בשל הגימטריה הזהה; פיסקה זו הוחזרה ברוב הסידורים, אך בחלקם מופיע בסוגריים. כמשקל נגד לטענה זו היו שחששו מהנוסח "ומושב יקרו", משום ש"יקרו" בגימטריה ישו, ומשפט זה נראה כמדבר בשבחו של מקים הדת הנוצרית. לכן הוכנסו בכתבי יד שינויי נוסחאות, דוגמת הסרת "ומושב יקרו", החלפה ב"וכיסא כבודו", ב"ומושבו היקר" ובגרסאות אחרות המעקרות את הגימטריה. הנוסח "וכיסא כבודו" אומץ על ידי הגר"א, הרב ישראל איסרלין, הרב יצחק אייזיק טירנא ואחרים, וכך נוהגים במנהג פפד"מ בימים נוראים כשאומרים עלינו בקול רם; אך המהר"ם מרוטנבורג, ובעקבותיו תשב"ץ והטור, אימצו את הגרסה המקובלת על פי ספר ההיכלות. בשם המהר"ם נמסר שאין לחשוש לגרסה "יקרו", שכן ״.אלו ראשי תיבות של "יה קדוש רם ונשא

It would seem that the original hint to ישו was “discovered” by the censors in the gimatria of וריק. This flight of fancy would not be out of character at all. Once this was pointed out, however, the issue of יקרו having the same gimatria becomes a legitimate concern.
